# Problem with RedirectoAction in Layout for logging out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionresult, redirecttoaction

I have an ActionLink in Shared layout like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home", new { @class = "navbar-btn btn btn-login" })
```

and in the controller of Home

```
public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Login","Home");
    }
```

Then when I press the `Logout` button, if the web page is within `/Home`, it return to the `/Home/Login` properly, with all session is cleared. But problem occur when I try to press Logout outside of `/Home`, e.g. in `/CourseUser`, the URL return then is `/CourseUser/Logout?Length=4`and it doesnt exist

What I wanted is to return the URL '/Home/Logout' under all circumstance when I press 'Logout'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kudos to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

The problem came from

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home", new { @class = "navbar-btn btn btn-login" })
```

The `Home` in this case is **route value**, not **controller name**.
Solution:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Đăng xuất", "Logout", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-btn btn btn-login", @type = "button" })
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink` will generate a link. Clicking it will result a HttpGet request to the server. That's fine for anything that doesn't change any state because HttpGet actions are supposed to be idempotent - calling it multiple times has the same effect.

For logging out, I think the best practices and standards out there recommend to use HttpPost, which you can implement using a hidden form post:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#form-logout').submit();">
    Logout
</a>

@using(Html.BeginForm("logout", "account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, 
  new { @id = "form-logout", @class = "d-none" }))
{
    @Html.AntiforgeryToken();
}
```

Clicking the link will trigger the hidden form's submition, which will post back the logout method defined in the controller, named `AccountController`, for example:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Cookies.Clear();

    return RedirectToAction("index", "dashboard", new { area = "" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add null in fourth parameter as following:

```
//parameters in order: title, action name , controller name , route values, html attributes
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home",null, new { @class = "navbar-btn btn btn-login" })
```

or you can do it without adding html attributes as following

```
//parameters in order: title, action name , controller name
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home" })
```